# Magento 2. Custom text in place of Price is not working Properly

Tags: magento2, frontend, plugin

In custom module I hide the Price and in the place of Price I tried to show Custom text it work perfectly but in some Categories it shows the custom text twice e.g men, Women. I can show the details in image and also going to upload the code as well thanks in Advance[image]

In other categories it shows the "For any Quaries Contact US" only once as you can see in the image.
[image]

but in "Men" and "Women" categories they show it twice as you guys can see it in image now my code is

> PME\Hideprice\Plugin

```
<?php

namespace PME\Hideprice\Plugin;

use PME\Hideprice\Helper\Data as Helper;

    class Price
    {

        public function __construct (
            Helper $helper,
            array $data = []
        ) {
                $this->helper = $helper;
        }



        function afterToHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $subject, $result) {
            // echo $this->helper->isCustomerLoggedIn(); exit;
            if($this->helper->getIsEnable())
            {
                if(!$this->helper->isCustomerLoggedIn())
                {       
                    return "<p>For any Quaries <a href='http://127.0.0.1/magento/contact/'>Contact Us </a></p>";
                }
            }         
            return $result;
        }

    }
```

> etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">


        <type name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox">
            <plugin name="price_hide" type="PME\Hideprice\Plugin\Price"/>        
        </type>

</config>
```

Comment: please check the product which showing twice message having special price

Comment: @Pawan can you please elaborate special price???? Actually for limit price like "50$ to 70$" it works perfectly but for "Men" and "Women" it shows Twice...

Answer (score 0):

Twice price issue of Configurable product like "Men" and "Women" categories. You want to hide price for guest user. Use below example it's working for me.

> File path: magento/app/code/PME/Hideprice/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'PME_Hideprice',
    __DIR__
);
```

> File path: magento/app/code/PME/Hideprice/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" 
        type="PME\Hideprice\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" 
        type="PME\Hideprice\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
</config>
```

> File path: magento/app/code/PME/Hideprice/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="PME_Hideprice" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

> File path:
>   magento/app/code/PME/Hideprice/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php

```
<?php
namespace PME\Hideprice\Pricing\Render;

use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox as BasePriceBox;
use Magento\Msrp\Pricing\Price\MsrpPrice;


class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{
    protected function wrapResult($html)
    {
     $result = '';
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $httpContext=$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
     $isLoggedIn = $httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);

     if($isLoggedIn){
       $result = '<div class="price-box ' . $this->getData('css_classes') . '" ' .
        'data-role="priceBox" ' .
        'data-product-id="' . $this->getSaleableItem()->getId() . '"' .
        '>' . $html . '</div>';
     }else{
        $result = "<p>For any Quaries <a href='http://127.0.0.1/magento/contact/'>Contact Us </a></p>";
     }
    return $result;
    }

}
```

Hope it help!